# Android OS (ICS) consumes more data in background in Funbook

Tags: data-monitoring, data-plan, micromax-funbook

I bought Micromax Funbook P3000 (All Winner A10-based clone) one month back and I have a 3G USB Dongle (Tata Photon+), I have a 10 GB plan, in that 5GB was used by Android OS itself. How to stop this as I find no option to "Stop background data"?